# Scheduling Task for future execution

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, task-parallel-library

I have looked at the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class API's, but could not find information on how to schedule a `Task` for future execution. 
Using the `Timer` class, I can schedule threads for future execution, but I need to schedule `Task`s.
`Task` has `.Delay(...)` methods, but not sure delay is similar to scheduling.

Edit(clarification): I want to start tasks after x minutes.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Do you want something to occur after a certain amount of time has elapsed? Use a Timer. What do you mean exactly by "future execution"?

Comment: Yes, lets say after 30 minutes, I want to fire up the task to do some operation.

Comment: `Task.Delay` internally uses `Timer` and yes answer is you're looking for a `Timer`. There are several timers available in .net framework, pick the right one for your scenario.

Comment: Desktop or Web environment? This will work in a desktop or service application. In a Web application, IIS will kill background threads once a request finishes processing. Do you want this for a Web application?

Comment: It will be a server application.

Comment: By "server application" you mean a Windows service? Web Services are "server applications" but behave as web applications

Comment: Not it will not be windows service. It will be just background threads/task running. Receive info - > start the thread to process the info -> Schedule the info for the deletion in x0 minutes -> delete and log the information

Comment: Why do you want to schedule an *execution*? It's so logical to schedule *creation* instead. Have a `Timer`, when time comes create a `Task` and run it. What's the whole point of creating `Task` in advance, but not running it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `Task.Delay` (which internally is implemented using a `System.Threading.Timer`):

```
async Task Foo()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
    // Do something
}
```

While the delay is "executed" [there is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) being used. When the wait ends the work after it would be scheduled for execution.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) Timer (System.Timers.Timer) instead. It's a bit simpler to use. Set the interval to 30 and start the timer, making sure the elapsed event calls the method you want to happen. You can stop it afterwards if you only want it to happen once and not every thirty minutes.

Code sample from the linked MSDN page:

```
// Create a timer with a two second interval.
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//schedule stuff to run after 2 seconds
Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t => {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, but the accepted answer has `async` signature. And sometimes .NET *does not allow you* to have it. Like in signature-bound factories for instance. The only other option is go "sync over async" which is *really-really* not the way to go.

Comment: `async` is not part of the signature.  It's an implementation detail of the method.  If the OP is in a situation where they are forced to implement a method with a synchronous signature (i.e. returning something other than a `Task` then *this answer does nothing to fix that problem* over the other answer.  So this solves no such problem (not that the question even indicates they *have* that problem).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This solution is still a bad idea regardless of such needs.  If they want a non-TPL solution, that's fine, but if they *do* want a TPL solution, this is a bad way to do it.  It's just always worse than existing answers, regardless of the needs described in the question.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's a strictly worse solution that existing solutions.  That an answer "technically works" despite being a poor answer doesn't change the fact that it's a poor answer, and uses techniques that are strongly advocated against using due to their lowlihood of causing problems when not used *very* carefully (in a way that this answer does not in fact do, by the way).  Votes are there to reflect how useful an answer is, not "whether it answers the question or, not, no matter how poorly".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That you think something is not a good solution *absolutely does matter*.  An upvote is specifically there to indicate that you think an answer is a high quality, useful solution that you *are recommending others use*.  So that you think it's not a solution that should be used is not irrelevant, in fact it's *highly* relevant.  It's the *only* relevant fact, even.

Comment: @Servy You wrote 4 comments stating it's "bad", "poor" and "advocated against" without pointing the actual "why's". Back on the topic: if you handle exceptions properly and mind that continuations may end up on another context, it's an OK solution.

Comment: It's much, much easier to make mistakes, and much harder to write proper code.  This is best exemplified by the fact that *you didn't do it right*.  You say that if you handle exceptions and contexts properly, *and yet you did neither of those things*.